# Which function should I use to close MATLink, DisconnectEngine or CloseMATLAB?

Tags: matlink

I'm using the MATLink package to call Matlab inside Mathematica. However, I want to know, if I want to close the link between Matlab and Mathematica, which function should I use? The `DisconnectEngine[]` or the `CloseMATLAB[]`?

The documents say that

> `CloseMATLAB[]` will close the currently open instance of MATLAB.

> `DisconnectEngine[]` will terminate the MathLink connection with the MATLAB engine.

It also provides an example of how to establish the link, namely, calling the following code

```mathematica
Needs["MATLink`"]
OpenMATLAB[]
```

However, it does not provide an example of how to close it.

Comment: What do you mean by "closing" it? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for your comment. I mean, once I've used the command `OpenMATLAB[]`, what should I do if I don't want to use it temporarily, like a python code for file operation need `f = open("demofile.txt", "r")` and an `f.close()` later on.

Comment: Nothing. You don't need to close it just because you don't use it temporarily. MATLAB will close automatically when the Mathematica kernel quits. If you want to force-quit the MATLAB process without shutting down Mathematica, use `CloseMATLAB[]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Oh, I see. Then, when should I use `DisconnectEngine[]`? I use Windows 10, and if I only use the command `CloseMATLAB[]`, the mangine.exe does not quit, see [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehWDB.png) and [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTXen.png)(task manager in Win 10).

Comment: The only reasons to use it that I can think of are development and debugging. Mathematica provides no means to unload packages, so there's no reason to shut down `mengine`.